# (Scheme) Using custom map and reduce, find minimum value in a list

Tags: list, dictionary, scheme, multiplication

I need to use the 2 functions below to find out the minimum value in a list after squaring every element.

For example: `(minSquare '(10 -2 5 9 -11)` should print out 4.

---

map and reduce code:

```
(define map
  (lambda (f l)
    (if (null? l)
        '()
        (cons (f (car l)) (map f (cdr l))))))

(define reduce
  (lambda (op l id)
    (if (null? l)
        id
        (op (car l) (reduce op (cdr l) id)))))
```

I tried this:

```
(define minSquare
  (lambda (x)
    (cond [(null? x) '()]
          [else (map minSquare (reduce * x (car x))) (minSquare (cdr x))])))
```

But that passes all the numbers in the list multiplied by their squares to `map` then crashes giving a `contract violation`. I'm not sure how to use those two functions.

If someone can guide me through it (not give the answer), I would greatly appreciate it!

**NOTE**: I can't modify `map` or `reduce`.

Comment: You probably want to do this in two passes: (1) square all the elements in the list, then (2) find the smallest element.

Comment: @AlexisKing Yes, that was my thinking, but I can't figure a way to do that. I tried passing the first element of the list to `reduce` with the `*` operator and `(car l)` for the id. I was hoping that would do -5*-5 but I just get an error saying it expects a pair. I can't modify map or reduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to `map` over the list squaring every element, and *after* that find the minimum using `reduce`. Some hints:

- `reduce` receives three parameters, the first is a procedure that compares each element with an initial minimum, updating its value whenever we find an element that is less than the current minimum.
- The second parameter is the list to traverse, which in this case is the result of squaring each of the elements: `(map (lambda (n) (* n n)) x)`.
- The third parameter is the initial minimum value, in this case is a number such that all the others will be less than it, for example the positive infinity `+inf.0`.

Notice that using `reduce` here is a bit of an overkill, given that the language already provides us with a `min` function.

Comment: Can you explain reduce? I thought it just did some mathematical operation on the list and the id passed. For example: `(reduce * '(1 2 3 4 5) 2)` will return `240` because it does `(1*2*3*4*5)*2`. What you're saying is a bit different. Am I using it wrong? I wish I could use the `min` function but since this is an assignment, I have to use both `map` and `reduce`.

Comment: So I think I understand it a bit better now. I did `(reduce < (map command up there) +inf.0)`. However, this gives me an error saying "< contract violation". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Vylic you asked for _hints_, not for a complete solution. If you want to understand `reduce`, take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29) - it's not just for doing mathematical operations, it consumes a list and produces a result.

Comment: @Vylic In your second attempt, passing `<` won't work, reduce expects a `lambda` with two parameters, the first one is the current element and the second one the accumulated value so far, and it must return the new accumulated value - in this case, the minimum. If the current element is less than the minimum, then return it; otherwise return the same minimum.

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally understand. It works great now. On top of that, I learned a lot from this.

Comment: @Vylic I'm very glad to hear that :) it's way more useful to learn things by yourself than to receive a direct answer, I liked the fact that you asked for guidance, not code.